# How do I best estimate population parameters from multiple sets of summary statistics on one sample?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, descriptive-statistics

Suppose that I have an assortment of summary statistics on a sample, and some beliefs about the underlying distribution, but no access to the sample itself. Each of the sets of summary statistics is sufficient to allow me to estimate the parameters of the distribution that I believe applies.  For, instance, I may have (1) the quintiles (quintile break points) (with published sample variance estimates for each), (2) the inter-quintile sample means (with variance estimates), and, (3) for some finer disaggregation into value categories, the number of observations that fall into each category (with variance estimates).

I know more or less how to do parameter estimates given any one of these summary statistics – though I am not sure how to make best use of the accompanying variance estimates for each. I could produce 3 distinct parameter estimates with a little work. But suppose I want to produce a single set of parameter estimates that makes the best use of all of the summary statistics that are available?

1. How would I combine the three (or however many I have – this is a simplified example) different types of summary statistics to get one set of parameters?
2. Can I make any further improvement to my parameter estimates by using the variance estimates that accompany each?

When I say “best” I am thinking maximum likelihood, but if there is an interestingly different and perhaps better answer for minimum mean square error estimates or MAP estimates or something, I’d love to know that too.